# how to packet capture between kubelet and apiserver

Tags: https, kubelet

i capture some traffic , kubelet connect to apiserver use  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

how to downgrade to TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256  ?

or

is there other way to debug connection between kubelet and apiserver?

i can't modify apiserver, but i can modify kubelet params and  restart kubelet

Comment: Could you please tell us what is the ultimate goal of your use case?

Comment: configmap sync between apiserver and kubelet is slow, i want to capture some traffic look is network slow

Comment: Is this behavior true only for ConfigMaps? I mean there is no delay with other resources in kubernetes? And how much time (aproximately - seconds, minutes) takes the synchronization between apiserver and kubelet (since you see that delay)?

Comment: sorry so late, i found what causes this:

 only configmaps sync slowly, because too many configmap write behavor, 
some plugin  use configmap as leader elect resource (k8s version is 1.16, lease resource not as default lock resource)